# PHP and function scope

Tags: php, function, scope

I was wondering what exactly happens when I do this:

```
$my_variable = 'foo';
function whatever(){
    $my_variable = 'bar';
    global $my_variable;
}
```

I know that, within the scope of the function `$my_variable` is now 'foo'.

What's going on internally? When I do   `$my_variable = 'bar';` inside my function, I've created a local variable. When I do `global $my_variable;` on the next line what exactly happens? The local one is automatically deleted?

Answer (score 2):

Up until the `global` is processed, the function will be using the local `bar` copy of the varaible. Once it's declared global, the local version is hidden (or maybe destroyed, not sure...) and only the global version is available. e.g:

```
$z = 'foo';
function whatever() {
    echo $z; // warning: undefined variable
    $z = 'bar';
    echo $z; // bar
    global $z;
    echo $z; // foo
}
whatever();
```

Comment: I believe when the `global` is called, the local version destroyed right there. I infer this from the action of `unset()` within a function and this statement in the [unset docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) : *If a globalized variable is unset() inside of a function, only the local variable is destroyed. The variable in the calling environment will retain the same value as before unset() was called.*

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, the local one is automatically deleted or probably better worded, it is replaced with the global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it like this:

```
$GLOBALS['my_variable'] = 'foo';
function whatever(){
    $my_variable = 'bar';
    $my_variable = $GLOBALS['my_variable'];
}
```